# Angular Module Loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have this module:

```
angular.module('myMod', [])
.factory('MyService', ['$http', 'Common', function ($http, Common) {
    var neededUrl = Common.myUrl;
}]);
```

And I loaded up my app modules this way:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'myMod'
])
.factory('Common', function () {
    return {
        myUrl: "/Some/Url"
    }
});
```

Will `myMod` be able to pick up on the `Common` dependency and load it up?

Or is it better to do this:

```
angular.module('common.module', [])
.factory('Common', function () {
    return {
        myUrl: "/Some/Url"
    }
});

angular.module('myApp', [
    'common.module',
    'myMod'
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both will work, but both are incorrect.

`MyService` from `myMod` depends on `Common`, not the other way around. Lets say you do choose to add `Common` to the module `common.module`. Then `myMod` should depend on `common.module`

```
angular.module('common.module', [])
.factory('Common', function () {
    return {
        myUrl: "/Some/Url"
    }
});


angular.module('myMod', [
    'common.module'
])
.factory('MyService', ['$http', 'Common', function ($http, Common) {
    var neededUrl = Common.myUrl;
}]);


angular.module('myApp', [
    'myMod'
]);
```

Using correct dependency management allows you to run isolated tests. The following is a jasmine example that should work:

```
describe('Test myMod', function() {

    beforeEach(module('myMod')); // from angular-mocks

    it('should work', function() {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    })
});
```

If you picked either one of the options you suggested, the test case would fail, because `MyService` does depend on `Common` from `common.module`.